# CSS Footer Style

Tags: html, css, salesforce

I am creating a pdf in salesforce and It displays a bulk data in 6 to 7 pages. My problem is, I am trying to display the page number on each page. But, instead, page number appears only in the last page. I am sure my logic is working fine but i am unsure about the 
CSS. The CSS I am using is,

CSS :

```
<div style="white-space:nowrap; top:99%; right:0px; position:absolute; font-size:10px; color:#155196" >
      page no 
<div>
```

I have changed it to bottom: 0px; but still its not working. This is my entire code for displaying page number.

```
<div style="white-space:nowrap;position:absolute;bottom:0%;  font-size:10px; color:#155196" >
       page {!p} of {!pageList.size} 
</div>
```

Thanks for your reply. My code looks like this.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!pageList}  var="p">
    <div style="white-space:nowrap;position:absolute;bottom:0%;  font-size:10px; color:#155196" >
            page {!p} of {!pageList.size} 
    </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

I dont know what's wrong in this code.

My output is

page {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} of 7. page number overlaps each other and displays it at the end.

Comment: Do not post your replies as an answers. Make them comments or edits to your post.

Answer (score 0):

it might help if we see some more of your code, but you ca try to change your `top:99%;` to `bottom:0px;` 
see a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eq5by/)

Answer (score 0):

instead of absolute you will give relative position then it will works fine

```
<div style="white-space:nowrap; position: relative; top: 0; bottom: 0;font-size:10px; color:#155196" >
      page no 
<div>
```